# PHP/Apache Rewrite for Subfolder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite setup:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /$1.php
```

I'm trying to any page under my `/admin` subdirectory (i.e. `/admin/index.php`, `/admin/users.php`, etc...) default to `/admin/`.

I thought I could add the following:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(\w+)\.php$ /admin/ [R=301]
```

After my existing 301 rewrite rule, but it's just creating a loop.

It's been a while since I wrote these rules, so I barely remember my mod rewrites and how I created them. (Not my strong suit.) Suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your complete .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(admin)/[^.]+\.php$ /admin/ [NC,L,R=301]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked splendidly and didn't break what I already had in place. I can't help but notice the difference in rewrite rules, though. Was I creating some issues or making my site slower by using the rules I had in place?

Comment: Mostly the difference is in regex. Adding `.php` internally should only be done after checking whether corresponding `.php` files exists. So yes my answer should improve speed also a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/admin/(\w+)\.php$ http://yourdomain/admin/ [R=301]
```